# How to concatenate two variables as selector in Less

Tags: css, css-selectors, concatenation, less

I'm trying to do something like this

```
@foo: lorem;
@bar: ipsum;

.@{foo}-@{bar} {
  // css-here
}
```

Expecting result:

```css
.lorem-ipsum {
  /** css-here
}
```

I only found out the Interpolation with one Variable,

```
.lorem-@{bar} { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found the answer, but don't know if it's the best or the only way to do it.

I tried appending `&` like this

```
.@{foo}&-@{bar} { ... }
```

and it worked.